# Ставится тире или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

Роман "Алая буква" - самый знаменитый.

Answer (score 1):

В таком предложении без контекста сложно решить задачу о постановке тире, это скорее не предложение, а часть предложения.

Возможные варианты:

1) Писатель является автором нескольких известных романов, но роман "Алая буква" **самый знаменИтый.**  Не ставим тире, если хотим **выделить сказуемое** (нет паузы, ударение на сказуемом).

2) Хотя писатель известен как автор многих книг,  **роман "Алая буква"** ― самый знаменитый. Ставим тире, если хотим **выделить подлежащее** (делается пауза, ударение на подлежащем).